# How to utilize Yeoman, AngularJS data, and Node.js to upload data into the Heroku starter database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, heroku, yeoman

My app is using Yeoman, AngularJS. I'm fairly new to it and so this questions is regarding managing data. Currently I am hard coding my data into an array of JSON object in my main.js file as such

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    //<--ARRAY OF DATA with multiple attributes<--
    $scope.campaigns = [
    { name:'', description'', etc... etc...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    {...Lots of Data...},
    ];
}]);
```

I am already deploying the site via heroku and so I wanted to upload this data into the starter dev Heroku Postgres Database. This is my first time uploading data to the heroku database and was wondering how I would go about this process. I want to use Node.js (also new for me) and I found this article (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js) but is this all I have to do? Where and how do I transfer my current array data into Node.js and then upload it to heroku?

---

Edit:
I followed the http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/, and http://www.lars-schenk.com/deploying-a-yeoman-angular-app-to-heroku/1661 articles (basically the same it seems) that @montecruiseto suggested and did a "grunt build" but the data is still lost when I refresh the page. This is my first time using Node.js but I believe these examples are deploying a static angular app without dynamic data update. What are the steps I need to take to take my current array data and utilize the "web.js" to make it persist up in the Heroku database?

Answer (score 0):

Why not run the [Yeoman-Heroku generator](https://github.com/passy/generator-heroku) over your existing app? Should take you a long step towards successful deployment.

Either way, this is pretty well documented for yo angular:

- [Deploy Yeoman App on Heroku](http://jaketrent.com/post/yeoman-app-on-heroku/)
- [Deploying a Yeoman/Angular app to Heroku](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/)
- [Deploying a Yeoman + Angular app to Heroku](http://www.lars-schenk.com/deploying-a-yeoman-angular-app-to-heroku/1661)
- [Deploying a Yeoman webapp to Heroku+Node.js](http://4lbertoc.blogspot.be/2013/01/deploying-yeoman-webapp-to-herokunodejs.html)
- [Easily deploy a build to Heroku with Grunt](http://www.vibesphere.com/2013/06/easily-deploy-a-build-to-heroku-with-grunt/)

Comment: Thank you for the resources. I followed the Deploying a Yeoman/Angular app to Heroku, and Deploying a Yeoman + Angular app to Heroku links (basically the same it seems) and did a "grunt build" but the data is still lost when I refresh the page. I think it is because those are deploying a static angular app without dynamic data update. How do I take my current array data and utilize the "web.js" to make it persist?